# Which thread library should I use for multithreaded C programs on Linux?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I've done threads in Java, but I'm a complete noob to threads in C. My first question, after googling some, is: Which thread library do I use? Does it matter? It seems I have `thread.h` and `pthread.h` to choose from.

OS is, and will be, Linux. More specifically, it's Ubuntu at the moment and will either stay like that, or become RHEL. But I guess the distro doesn't matter?

Comment: Where on the filesystem do you have `thread.h` ?

Comment: @pilcrow - didn't look in the file system, saw it in some tutorials, with methods like `thr_create`. It doesn't appear to be widespread, or maybe I got something wrong. I'm using pthreads now, so it doesn't matter anymore.

Comment: That's probably the native thread API of SunOS/Solaris, which might have answered your question right off the bat. :)

Comment: @pilcrow - You are very probably right. :)

Comment: The answer to this question helped me to overcome web search confusion, and after doing a lot of reading on POSIX threads, I realize just how newbie this question is. Hope it helps other noobs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The POSIX thread libraries ([**`pthread.h`**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/pthread.h.html)) are a standards based thread API for C/C++ and is what I would use.  There are also several tutorials available such as [this one](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialPosixThreads.html) or [this one](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/).

I will admit that I am not familiar with `thread.h`.

Answer (score 1):

The standard thread interface on POSIX systems such as linux is pthread, for POSIX thread.