# POSIX C PROGRAM(MUTEX PROGRAM)

Tags: c, pthreads

I am a beginner in C programming and I am trying to perform mutex on the program below, but I'm not getting the proper output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#define NUM_THREAD 4
void *func(void *p);
int counter=0,a=2;
pthread_mutex_t mutexsum = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

main()
{
    int i,rc;
    pthread_t threadid[NUM_THREAD];

    for(i = 0; i< NUM_THREAD; i++)
    {
        a = a + i;
        printf("Value of a is %d\n",a);
        rc = pthread_create(&threadid[i],NULL,func,(void *)a);
        if(rc)
        {
            printf("Error in thred creation thread[%d] %d",i,rc);
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i< NUM_THREAD; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(threadid[i],NULL);
    }

    printf("Final value of counter is %d\n",counter);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *func(void *p)
{
    int i;
    i = (int) p;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexsum);
    counter = counter+a;
    printf("%d\n",counter);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexsum);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

As per the above program and my understanding, the desired output will be 18, but it's giving 32.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`func` uses `a` to increment. I'm guessing you meant to increment by `i`. As it is, by the time each thread runs, `a` must be at its final value of 8, so you are adding 8 to `counter` four times.

Comment: Dear Marcelo,  Thanks for your reply.Yes   it's using value of a i.e. 8 for each thread it means that firstly all thread is created after that it is using final value of a i.e.8.But instead of this I want to use new value of a i.e. coming from each iteration of for loop. For eg. when value of i is 0 then value of a become 2 so I want that thread[1]  will use 2 instead of 8.similarly when  i=1 then  value of a becomes 3 so thread[2] has value 3.                      I hope now it's clear.Please let me inform if you require any more clarification from my end.  Thanks in advance!!!.

Comment: Perhaps my answer was unclear. Replace `counter+a` with `counter+i`. Also, `a` doesn't need to be a global; move it inside `main()`.

Comment: Dear Marcelo,  Thanks a lot for your response and could please provide me some links for pthread tutorial.  Once again thanks a lot for your response.

Comment: That's as simple as googling for "pthreads tutorial". However, I don't know of any pthreads tutorial that gives you a good grasp of the principles of concurrent programming. Frankly, as a beginner, you should avoid threads entirely. While they are, on the surface, a fairly straightforward concept, there are innumerable pitfalls lurking just beneath the surface. Many large and useful systems are written entirely without threads, and threads aren't the only concurrency mechanism available to you.

Comment: See [here](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.eecs.berkeley.edu%2FPubs%2FTechRpts%2F2006%2FEECS-2006-1.pdf) for more info.

Comment: [@user671112](http://stackoverflow.com/users/671112) - This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5247812/203667#52478877) has a few links to pthread tutorials.  As a beginner, the [second tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) in the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5247812/203667#52478877) may be a good place to start.  I do agree with Marcelo's statement regarding the use of pthreads by a beginner in C programming, but it shouldn't hurt to read through a few tutorials.

Comment: Dear marcelo and jschmier, Thanks a lot for your response and guidence.actually i m studying c from last 3 months and now i have basic understanding of c like pointer,aaray,structure,file handling.Can you please tell me how can i improve my skills so that in future I would become expert in C.  Once again thanks for your guidence.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using *i* in your thread function, but *a*.